# How hard is it to create a monero wallet site?

Tags: implementation

There aren't a lot of monero based sites around, and I think there is a lot of opportunity, but I don't really know much about implementing crytocurrency into a website. I figured I might try to start by creating a wallet site, but I wanted to ask if anyone could provide any insight onto the difficulty of that? I may be way in over my head but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you mean a full wallet website where users can receive and make payments? How confident are you that you can provide a website that is secure and will adequately protect your users' wallets? You can't do 99% secure: you must aim at 100% secure and that requires time, knowledge and experience.

Comment: There is an online wallet mymonero.com which I read somewhere will be opensouce sometime in the future. I can say it is safe since you don't store your spent keys/private keys on the server. Your keys are generated on the client and transactions I think are signed locally on the client browser then submitted (not too sure yet). This means that you will not worry too much on securing your server. One downside of this online wallet is that if you created your wallet somewhere and restore your wallet it would not be able to see previous transactions. You have the option to pay where it would scan

Comment: @Gundamlancer in general mymonero.com is quite safe, since it doesn't send your seed or private spend keys to the server. However, if an attacker would compromise the server, they could change the source code to get your seed (or private spend keys). Also due to SSL authority flaws I would possibly not exclude a Man in the middle attack. I trust fluffypony, that he cares a lot about security of his server and the service in general, but I wouldn't hold tons of Moneroj there.

Answer (score 7):

It would be moderately easy to get a working wallet site provided you know some basic programming (python, php, node.js) and a little about web server usage (linux!).

You just need to run a full node on your server, create a wallet, then write some code which checks for payments, makes payments etc. See [wallet-RPC](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc) for some guidance on this.

As already mentioned, the challenge here would be to implement these things securely/reliably. Making something like this for public use is not recommended unless you know exactly what you are doing. Just imagine if all your users monero was stolen or lost - you'll certainly end up in hot water.

You're right though that there is a lot of opportunity in this space. I encourage you to at least experiment with your idea (i.e get a full node working on your server and programmatically check your balance). Its the best way to learn and from there you'll have a better feeling of what you can do with this technology.

Comment: Thank you for this, was definitely the kind of answer I was looking for. I get the point that the other person made about how it would be rather difficult to have a safe/secure service. But I would definitely like to experiment with it and see how everything works.